# How do I identify the segue entry point in the destination controller?

Tags: ios5, storyboard, segue

is there a way to identify the segue identfier used to navigate, inside the destination viewcontroller.

Comment: what is that you want to do? I just ask because maybe there is another way to do whatever it is.

Comment: Hi. my question is that if i have multiple entry points to a view i would love to know from where i have actually entered and execute a simple code specific to that entry... such as assigning some bundle variables or executing a code for that specific instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in that case in the viewController you are coming from override prepareForSegue: and pass some data in to the destination viewController that will allow it to decide what specific code to run.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueIdentifier"]) {
        YourViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.yourData = yourData;
    }
}
```

the in viewDidLoad of the destination check the value of yourData and execute your custom code

Comment: this is was i ended up doing was wondering if there was any other way. thanks for the input.